# How to use trigger with 3 different tables

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

Dear Fellow StackOverFlow-members,

I have 3 tables. **bdc(bdc_id, bdc_name, bdc_gc)**, **stt(stt_id, stt_gc)**, **bts(bts_id, bts_pmv)**.

I want if `stt_gc = 'Checked'` then set `bdc_gc = 'Sent'` and `bts_pmv = 'To do'`

I use Postgresql **11** and beginning with triggers/stored procedures
I tried to check with `if` condition `stt_gc` value and matching with the right `bdc_gc` `bts_pmv` according to their primary key.

```
create or replace function before_stt_gc() returns trigger
  language plpgsql
as
$$
begin

    if new.stt_gc='Checked' then
      select bdc_gc from bdc
      where new.stt_id = bdc_id;
      doe_gc_bts= 'Sent';
      select bts_pmv from bts
      where new.stt_id = bts_id;
      bts_pmv = 'To do'
    end if;
  end;
$$;

create trigger before_stt_gc_trigger before insert or update on stt
  for each row 
  execute procedure before_stt_gc();
```

Obviously if I'm here it's because my code is totally wrong... 
I want to learn from this, so if possible, explain me what I'm doing wrong here, or if my approach is lacking insight

Comment: Aside from telling you that you can't have SELECT statements in a plpgsql function without a destination for the result, it's not clear to me what exactly your question is. And your naming convention is terrible.

Comment: So i can't have a SELECT whithout a INTO, is it what you're saying ?
My question is written above. I want to set value of bdc_gc and bts_pmv when an insert or an update set stt_gc = 'Checked' . 
What do you suggest me to do about my naming convention to make it better ?

Comment: Naming convention: Use proper words instead of abbreviations, and don't prefix the columns in the tables with the table name. Select: in plpgsql, if you do a SELECT you have to have a destination. So either `SELECT ... INTO` or `var1 := (SELECT ...)`. To run a SELECT and completely discard the output, you have to use PERFORM: `PERFORM col1 FROM table`.

Comment: @404 I don't use abbreviations. These are propers used by user who are using this database.
And you says don't prefix the colums. Do you mean I should for example name the colum `gc` instead of  `bdc_gc` ?
Well thank you for the tips. I wans't aware of PERFORM function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are looking for  `update`s within the `IF` statement

```
if new.stt_gc='Checked' then
  update  bdc  set bdc_gc = 'Sent'
  where new.stt_id = bdc_id;

 UPDATE bts SET bts_pmv = 'To do'
  where new.stt_id = bts_id;

end if;
```

Comment: It is exactly what i was missing. The `update` within an `if` statement. As I said I'm very knew to this and I didn't I could use `update` like this.
However you inserted a `;` in between the `update`s that makes an error.
Otherwiser thank you dude !

Comment: @LyessD : You're welcome! It was a copy paste error, removed now.